# Oracle SQL Developer shows only sql errors in logfile or "Messages - Log"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using `Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.0.3.16`

I have a `test_script.sql` where I try to make some test Data Manipulation to test my constraints like `DELETE FROM`.

I have

[image]

which gives me a log file of my whole `.sql` script and all errors.
[image]

The Problem is, if the script is long it is very annoying to search for all the errors.

Is there a way to show only the errors `Error starting at line : 43 in command -` in `Oracle SQL Developer`

I have another window in `Oracle SQL Developer` which is called `Messages-Log`

[image]

But there are the errors not shown too. I would need a window which shows only me all the errors in the script and maybe if you click on the error that you automatically get navigated to the `.sql` line where your error came from.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

You can however, use Ctrl+F to look for and navigate to errors.

You can also double click on error messages and be taken to the line where the error occurred in the original script. [See here for an example of that](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/08/sql-worksheet-error-hyperlinking-in-oracle-sql-developer-v4/).